# Converting columns to rows and giving them a number

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with this format:

```
df
name,status,text
stock1,open,text1 
stock1,closed,text something here
```

and I would like to convert it like this:

```
name,status1,status2,text1,text2
stock1,open,closed,text1,text something here
```

How can I convert its columns to rows without know the exact number of columns?

Comment: You can also use `spread` from `tidyr`

Comment: This question has likely been asked literally 1000's of times here on the `r` tag. Did you search at all?

Comment: @thelatemail No need for search or effort when the helpful people on SO provide a tailor-made answer in no time anyway. Good'ol codez-repz symbiosis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `library(data.table)` which can take multiple `value.var` columns.

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'name', we create a sequence column ('N'), then use `dcast` and specify the `value.var` columns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, N:= 1:.N, name]
dcast(df1, name~N, value.var=c("status", "text"))
#    name status_1 status_2 text_1              text_2
#1: stock1     open   closed text1  text something here
```

---

Or a `base R` option is `reshape` after creating a sequence column by "name".

```
df2 <- transform(df1, N= ave(seq_along(name), name, FUN=seq_along))
reshape(df2, idvar="name", timevar="N",direction="wide")
#   name status.1 text.1 status.2              text.2
#1 stock1     open text1    closed text something here
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("stock1", "stock1"), 
status = c("open", 
"closed"), text = c("text1 ", "text something here")), 
.Names = c("name", 
"status", "text"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thank you. It is perfect for me! Just an additional question if I have more value like a name stock2 but it is not contains for example the status could be possible to add NA values with d cast or should I add something?

Comment: @Berbery If it doesn't have any value, the `dcast` should fill it by `NA` as default or you can specify the `fill=` argument